# Transferring a TextView from View 1 and implementing it in View 2 swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, textview, uitextview

I have a TextView in View 1 and a button in View 2(to change the font)

When I drag the TextView into View2 to execute it inside the Button gives me an error:

```
Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)
```

View1

```
@IBOutlet weak var detilesTextview: UITextView!
```

View2

```
var arl : UIFont?
@IBAction func Font1 (_ sender: Any) {
    
    let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "ViewSendQuestion") as! ViewSendQuestion
    
    vc.detilesTextview.font = arl
    arl = UIFont(name: "Futura", size: 40)
    present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

I want to change the font in the TextView in View 1
Through the button in View 2

Comment: Can you post images declaring what you wanna achieve?

Comment: I have a text in View 1 and I want to put a button that changes the font in View 2

Comment: You mean you want to change the font from the button in view2 ? At least 2 ways : use delegation or use notification (may depend how you transition from view1 to view2)

Comment: What are these ways? I use ContainerView inside View 1

Comment: The question is a bit vague;  *When I drag the TextView into View2* - what does that mean, 'drag the TextView'? Do you mean drag the text from one view to another? Also, you're creating a ViewSendQuestion view inside View2 - what does that have to do with View1? Can you clarify what you're attempting to do and provide more details about what view does what?

Comment: The ultimate goal is to save fonts in Firebase

Comment: I have a lot of Font, how can I save them?